# Animating one of three boxes based on a form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Is there a better way to do this without using `if` or `case` statements?

```
var val = ui.value,
$box = $('#message');
switch(true) {
  case (val > 50):
    $box.hide();
    animations.animateBox($box.html('you have chosen XN'));                        
    break;
  case (val < 50):
    $box.hide().delay(300);
    animations.animateBox($box.html('you have chosen VN'));
    break;
  default:
    $box.hide();
    animations.animateBox($box.html('you have chosen PN'));
}
```

Comment: Although `switch` can be used with expressions, you should better only use literal/constant values.

Comment: That's a very wrong use of a switch statement

Comment: Would it be simpler to go with a if..else if..else construct. I don't understand your use of switch here.

Comment: Conditional logic. Better way to do this without using if or case. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 18):

This **completely replaces** your `switch` statement by using <strike>inline if statements</strike> **conditional** operator:

```
$box.hide().delay(val < 50 ? 300 : 0);
var s = val > 50 ? 'XN' : (val < 50 ? 'VN' : 'PN');
animations.animateBox($box.html('you have chosen ' + s));
```

the first line could be replaced by these two arguably more readable lines that omit the call to `delay()` function when not applicable:

```
$box.hide();
val < 50 && $box.delay(300);
```

Since @GregGuida pointed out that this code is less readable I suppose I can make it more readable by better formatting it. And I'll use the suggestion of replacing the first line with two of them:

```
$box.hide();

// only delay animation when value < 50
val < 50 && $box.delay(300);

var s = val > 50 ? 'XN' :
       (val < 50 ? 'VN' :
                   'PN');
// set HTML
animations.animateBox($box.html('you have chosen ' + s));
```

Same code but visually less chaotic (even without comments it would look less chaotic) and much much more readable. At least much more readable than OP's original code. **That I'm sure of.** Readability is of course an argumentative disposition. But I'll leave that to others.

Comment: The only thing I would change us abstracting out the conditions into variables. Like `var isXN=val>50;` but that's just me. +1

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is 100 times harder to read. this is code review not [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @GregGuida: That may be, hence the two line replacement suggestion for the first line. But for the rest it does remove the excessive if statement and switch statement that OP was after. Quote: *Is there a better way to do this without using if or case statements* Unquote. My answer is **exactly that**. No `switch` nor `if` statement if we say that inline `if` is not an `if`... At least it doesn't seem like one.

Comment: Your cleanup makes it much more readable, I guess I just disagree with the "no if" part of the question. If ever there was a place to use `if ... if else ... else` this is it. Also not to be a JS snob, but its called a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Ternary's still technically an if. You're just not actually writing "if" in the code. The "without if" bit of the question is kind of absurd though.

Comment: @BenBrocka: It would be absurd if it said _without code branching_. :)

Comment: @GregGuida: You're right. Inline if isn't the correct term. You're right it's called **conditional operator**.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik between no case and no if (and the ternary operator really is an if IMO) you've pretty much run out of conditional operators in any standard coding style.

Comment: @BenBrocka: jump tables can take the place of conditional operators, and in really large cases that's what you probably want to use.  Of course, three isn't really large...

Answer (score 14):

You **must not** use conditional statements in combination with `switch`... that is THE DEVIL... because `switch/case` only interpretates **values** !

Infact, what you did there equals

```
switch( true ) {
    case true/false:
       break;
    case true/false:
       break;
    etc.
}
```

That is ohhh-so-wrong! Only use `switch` if you have well defined states/values which you want to check for. You totally should go with a `if/else` statement there.

```
if( val > 50 ) {
}
else if( val < 50 ) {
}
else { // val equals 50
}
```

Comment: You are writing this as if it's technically wrong use `switch` the way Amit did, however technically it's not wrong at all. It is of course wrong, because it's a bad code style and affects readability.

Comment: I agree with @RoToRa. Switch statement like that works. If it was wrong it wouldn't work. Whether it's safe to do it this way or whether it aids readability it's a different question and an argumentative one.

Comment: @jAndy: when you say `case true/false` it's actually the same with every case statement. The variable in switch is either of some value or it's not. The same with these expressions... So technically switch statement with case expressions is argumentative in its nature at best.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Well, a `switch` statement is intended to check a variable for multiple values/states. The usage in the OPs code is totally confusing and potentially dangerous. Since his expressions can only end up beeing `true` or `false` you will never be able to have more than 2 `cases`. So again, this is pure evil.

Comment: You could quite easily have as many true/false cases as you want.  The `switch` statement in JS is much more flexible than Java's or C's; it has no requirement that case values be unique, and doesn't require a constant/literal for the case expression.  It'll just start at the first case that evaluates equal to the `switch` expression.  The `switch (true)` thing is ugly, and an abuse of `switch`, and not optimizable into a jump table, but it's quite valid JS -- and any interpreter that can't deal with it is broken.

Comment: @jAndy: I must totally agree with cHao... You can have many `case`-es as you need. They could be: **case (val < 50)** and next **case (val < 100)** and next **case (val < 150)** and so on and so forth. Javascript will go checking from one to the next to the next etc... Until it gets to one that returns `true`. Basically. Javascript will evaluate each when it runs not in front. But even though if it was evaluating before execution it would be important that **only one be `true` and all the rest would be `false` so it would know exactly which one to execute...

Comment: its a complete missuse of the statement and I'm still absolutely convinced it will always be trouble and confusion. Even if its not "technically wrong", its still wrong (imo).

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
var val = ui.value,
    $box = $('#message');
    var choice = (val > 50) ? 'XN' : ((val < 50) ? 'VN' : 'PN');

    if(val < 50) {
        $box.hide().delay(300);
    } else {
        $box.hide();
    };

    animations.animateBox($box.html('you have chosen ' + choice));
```

You could remove the IF statement altogether if it weren't for the delay().

Comment: What does .delay(0) ?

Comment: var delayAmount=(val<50)?300:0;
$box.hide().delay(delayAmount);

Comment: delay stops execution for the number of milliseconds indicated.  http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Here's a simple example. http://jsfiddle.net/Ccugd/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional operator of you want to avoid `if` and `switch`. You can reduce some repetiton in the code using a variable for the chosen product:

```
var val = ui.value,
var box = $('#message');
box.hide().delay(val < 50 ? 300 : 0);
var product =
  val > 50 ? 'XN' :
  val < 50 ? 'VN' :
  'PN';
animations.animateBox(box.html('you have chosen ' + product));
```

You should still consider if the code is more readable using `if` statements:

```
var val = ui.value,
var box = $('#message');
box.hide();
if (val < 50) {
  box.delay(300);
}
var product;
if (val > 50) {
  product = 'XN';
} else if (val < 50) {
  product = 'VN';
} else {
  product = 'PN';
}
animations.animateBox(box.html('you have chosen ' + product));
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

1. use ternary operators;
2. use single char;
3. for prevent type casting, compare defined values with undefined;
4. use logical "and" (`&&`) instead of `if`.

Code snippet:

```
var val = ui.value,
    box = $('#message'),
    chr = 50 > val ? 'V' : (50 < val ? 'X' : 'P');
box.hide();
50 > val && box.delay(300);
animations.animateBox(box.html('You have chosen ' + chr + 'N'));
```